# Using scrapy to get second page of results that uses Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape http://www.sueryder.org/Get-involved/Volunteering/All-Roles, as you can see if you click on the second page the URL of the page doesn't change and it is processed through javascript. I've been trying to use the network tab in "inspect element" but I am completely lost. I managed to scrape the first page of the website and here's the code.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy_demo.items import ScrapyDemoItem


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "test"
  allowed_domains = ["sueryder.org"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.sueryder.org/Get-involved/Volunteering/All-Roles"]

  def parse(self, response):
      hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
      titles = hxs.select('//tr')
      items = []
      for titles in titles:
          item = ScrapyDemoItem()
          item ["link"] = titles.select('td/text()').extract()
          items.append(item)
      return items
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I have looked at that hence me inspecting the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript just submits a form, so use `FormRequest`:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

for href in hxs.select('//div[@class="paging pag-num pag-arrows"]//a/@href'):
    target = href.split("'")[1]

    yield FormRequest.from_response(
        response=response, 
        formnumber=0,
        formdata={'__EVENTTARGET': target}
    )
```

You'll also have to subclass `CrawlSpider` and setup a `Rule` to crawl the result pages, as doing it within `parse` will not work.

Comment: Thank you Blender - I will check this out later today. Seems to make sense

Comment: Ok sorry for this noob question, first time using the class CrawlSpider. Do I place the "href in hxs.select" in the "restrict_xpaths" within the rule? Do I also need an "allow"?

Comment: @user2927435: `CrawlSpider` has a `rules` class attribute that lets you create simple rules to follow links and pass crawled pages off to callbacks. You want to create a rule that follows all of the links in a given page of results and passes the crawled page off to a callback like `parse_result`.